# How to get video file link, just after i uploaded it with VimeoAPI

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm developing a TV app, and I'm need the video file link just after a user upload a video, for saving it on the database and using the link in the android external player. The back-end is taking all the work related to vimeo, here is the code that gets the video infos

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
        vimeo.request(
          {
            method: 'GET',
            path: `${uri}`,
          },
          (error, body) => {
            if (error) console.log(error)
            resolve(body)
          },
        )
      })
```

When I make this request, the "files" field come empty,
thanks already, anything would be helpful.